# How to redirect a url containing specific strings and Percentage (%) character

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, special-characters, percentage

Here are my example urls:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/login/return_url/64-L21wMy1tdXNpYy9zZWFyY2gvc2luZ2VyL3RpdGxlL05vc2EvcGFnZS80
http://www.mywebsite.com/login/return_url/64-L21wMy1tdXNpYy9hbGJ1bXMvNjM%3D
http://www.mywebsite.com/login/return_url/64-L21wMy1tdXNpYy9hbGJ1bXMvMzcyLw%3D%3D
http://www.mywebsite.com/login/return_url/64-L21wMy1tdXNpYy9hbGJ1bXMvNDIwLw%3D%3D
http://www.mywebsite.com/login/return_url/64-L2xvZ2luL3JldHVybl91cmwvNjQtTDIxd015MXRkWE5wWXk5aGJHSjFiWE12TXpJeEx3JTNEJTNE
http://www.mywebsite.com/login/return_url/64-L21wMy1tdXNpYy9hbGJ1bXMvMjA%3D
```

I like to redirect all url that contains 64-L21 like the ones listed above to http://www.mywebsite.com/login/

I have tried:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} 64-L21
RewriteRule .* /login/ [R,L]
```

The above rule works very fine for urls like

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/login/return_url/64-L21wMy1tdXNpYy9zZWFyY2gvc2luZ2VyL3RpdGxlL05vc2EvcGFnZS80
http://www.mywebsite.com/login/return_url/64-L21wMy1tdXNpYy9hbGJ1bXMvNjM
```

but it doesn't work whenever there is percentage sign (%) in the url

can someone pls provide an htaccess rule to address the percentage sign (%), i want both urls with and without the sign to redirect

Thanks in advance

Comment: works for me, which Apache version do you have and what error are you getting?

Comment: Simply use `RewriteRule ^login/return_url/64-L21 /login/ [R,L]`

Comment: @anubhava I am not getting any error, i just want to redirect because all these urls serves the same content

Comment: @hjpotter92 ur suggestion works for only urls that has no percentage sign (%). it doesn't work for: http://www.mywebsite.com/login/return_url/64-L21wMy1tdXNpYy9hbGJ1bXMvMzcyLw%3D%3D

Comment: For me this rule is redirecting for `http://www.mywebsite.com/login/return_url/64-L21wMy1tdXNpYy9hbGJ1bXMvMzcyLw%3D%3D` URL also.

Comment: @anubhava try this http://www.songstoshare.com/login/return_url/64-L21wMy1tdXNpYy9zZWFyY2gvY2F0ZWdvcmllcy9wYWdlLzEwL2lkLzE%2Fc2VhcmNoPWNhdGVnb3JpZXM%3D

Comment: Yes that also got redirected. Are you on shared hosting or can control server settings to?

Comment: @anubhava i can control server settings

Comment: ok check your Apache error.log when entering `http://www.songstoshare.com/login/return_url/64-L21wMy1tdXNpYy9zZWFyY2gvY2F0ZWdvcmllcy9wYWdlLzEwL2lkLzE%2Fc2VhcmNoPWNhdGVnb3JpZXM%3D` There will be 404 but see what URL does Apache get and what error it writes.